# How to ensure that coffeescript is loaded sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have two coffeescript files, A and B, in the same folder. I want A to execute up to a point, then run B, then continue executing. In other words, I want this:

```
//in A
$("#content").html(@currentView.el)
require ['B']

//in B
if document.location.href.indexOf("showdiv") > 0
    $("#content").trigger('click')
```

However, if I put everything into A, it works fine:

```
//in A
$("#content").html(@currentView.el)

if document.location.href.indexOf("showdiv") > 0
    $("#content").trigger('click')
```

How can I get the first snippet to work? Is the require keyword making the compiled javascript load in parallel?

Comment: This is speculation as I'm not very familiar with CoffeeScript, but I think there's a lot wrong here. Why are you using square brackets for `require`? And if this is mean to run client-side, I'm pretty sure there's no such thing as `require` in client-side JavaScript. Your code basically boils down to a series of `<script src=...>` tags and you can't include one script from within another script this way. I believe `require` is something provided by Node.js for server-side JavaScript.

Comment: you're right, I think that require is a rails keyword. I ended up created a global function in the second file and calling that function from the first.

Comment: It looks like you're doing this from rails, yes? In that case, you should probably learn about the rails asset pipeline: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the browser you control the load order by how you pull in your code in your html file. Here's an example from one of my projects (in `index.html`, just before the closing `body` tag):

```
  <script src="vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/pouch.alpha.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/backbone-pouchdb.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/backbone-couchdb.js"></script>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The last one is the one that kicks things off, similar to the "main" function in C if that makes any sense to you. In it, there is this construct (compiled to js of course):

```
$(document).ready ->
  # Initialization code goes here
```

The initialization code will either include all the code in your original posting (minus the require calls which do not exist in the browser), or call a function containing it. The reason you need to delay your script execution in the manner shown above is to delay execution until all the code has loaded properly.

There are other ways to do it, and one you may be confusing with is the concept of Javascript AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition) and you can read more about it on one of the libraries for it (RequireJS - http://requirejs.org). But my advice would be to master the basics as I've described above before trying to get AMD (with tools) going.